# Read integers from a text file with C++ ifstream

Tags: c++

I want to read graph adjacency information from a text file and store it into a vector.

- the file has arbitrary number of lines
- each line has arbitrary number of integers ended with '\n'

for example,

```
First line:
0 1 4
Second line:
1 0 4 3 2
Thrid line:
2 1 3
Fourth line:
3 1 2 4
Fifth line:
4 0 1 3
```

If I use getline() to read one line at a time, how do I parse the line (as each line has variable number of integers)?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The standard line reading idiom:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
std::string line;

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  int n;
  std::vector<int> v;

  while (iss >> n)
  {
    v.push_back(n);
  }

  // do something useful with v
}
```

---

Here's a one-line version using a `for` loop. We need an auxiliary construction (credits to @[Luc Danton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726300/luc-danton)!) that does the opposite of `std::move`:

```
namespace std
{
  template <typename T> T & stay(T && t) { return t; }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv;

  for (std::string line;
       std::getline(std::cin, line);
       vv.push_back(std::vector<int>(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::stay(std::istringstream(line))),
                                     std::istream_iterator<int>())
                    )
       ) { }

  std::cout << vv << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That means, this is using C++11 feature, as `&&` is available only in C++11.

Comment: @Nawaz: My earlier version involves a more elaborate struct and a const-cast, which is C++98. Talk to me in private if you're interested, it's not suitable for polite conversation :-)

Comment: @Kerrek, Thanks for your solution. When I have nested STL container, say, vector<vector<int> >, how do I iterate through it? I was trying the following:   std::vector<std::vector<int> > iter1;
  std::vector<int>::iterator iter2;
  for (iter1 = vv.begin(); iter1 != vv.end(); ++iter1) {
    for (iter2 = (*vv).begin(); iter2 != (*vv).end(); ++iter2)
      cout << *iter2 << " ";
    cout << endl;
  }
It doesn't compile. What is the proper way of iterating through a nested STL container. Thanks.

Comment: @itnovice: It's something like that. `for (std::vector<std::vector<int>>::const_iterator it1 = v.begin(), end1 = v.end(); it1 != end1; ++it1) { for ( std::vector<int>::const_iterator it2 = it1->begin(), end2 = it1->end(); it2 != end2; ++it2) { ... } }` etc.

Comment: @Kerrek: Thanks for your reply. It does the job.

Comment: @itnovice: Cheers, I'm glad. Use the first version. The second one was purely for "I'll be damned if that can't be done in one line."

Comment: "`std::stay`" Since when is it allowed to add names to `std`?

Answer (score 9):

First read a line using `std::getline` function, then use `std::stringstream` to read the integers from the line as:

```
std::ifstream file("input.txt");

std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv;
std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    int i;
    std::vector<int> v;
    while( ss >> i ) 
       v.push_back(i);
    vv.push_back(v);
}
```

You can also write the loop-body as:

```
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::istream_iterator<int> begin(ss), end;
    std::vector<int> v(begin, end);
    vv.push_back(v);
}
```

This looks shorter, and better. Or merge-the last two lines:

```
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::istream_iterator<int> begin(ss), end;
    vv.push_back(std::vector<int>(begin, end));
}
```

Now don't make it shorter, as it would look ugly.

Comment: Or even `for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line); vv.push_back(std::vector<int>(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::istringstream(line)), std::istream_iterator<int>()))) {}`

Comment: @KerrekSB: Hehe. Good one. I like the idea of minimizing the scope of `line` variable.

Comment: Just testing it, but it might be that you can't get the iterator from a temporary string stream :-(

Comment: The iterator can only be constructed from a non-constant reference. So you can't construct it from an rvalue, unfortunately.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Oh I see. In that case, if you replace `std::istringstream(line‌​)` with `static_cast<std::stringstream&>(std::stringstream().flush() << line)`, then it will work. See this : http://www.ideone.com/r0T0X ... but it is better to avoid such code, in my opinion!

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks Nawaz. Your solution's awesome.

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks Nawaz. Your solution's awesome. I am not quite sure about <prev> <code> std::istream_iterator<int> begin(ss), end;</br> std::vector<int> v(begin, end);
</code></prev>. Is that an alternate way of doing <prev> <code> copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(v); </code> </prev>?

Comment: @itnovice: Yes. It is same as `std::copy` version, but it is better than that as it is using the constructor of vector directly.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Or you can write `++(std::istream_iterator<int>(static_cast<std::stringstream&>(std::stringstream() << 100 <<" " << line)))`. Any integer can be used in place of `100`. I hope you understand the rationale here. Code : http://www.ideone.com/9tSV5

Comment: @Nawaz: impressive -- no, I'm not sure I understand. Why is the return value not an rvalue anymore? Can the same be achieved more simply with a function that returns a reference to its argument?

Comment: @KerrekSB: There are many things to consider : 1) you cannot make copy of a stream, 2) which means you've to pass it by reference to a free function, 3) since it is originally a rvalue, it cannot be bound to a non-const reference, but if you bind it to a const reference, the function cannot return non-const reference. 4) all these imply that this cannot be achieved by using a free function. [Contd.].

Comment: [Contd.] 5) but since a member function can be invoked on a rvalue and the function can return non-const reference by use of `return *this`, the code works as expected. Now there are many member functions which returns `std::istream&`, for example `std::istream::flush` and `operator<<(int)`. That is why I gave these two examples.

Comment: @Nawaz: The question is, why can a `*this` returned from a member function of an rvalue suddenly be an lvalue?

Comment: @KerrekSB: A more intriguing question, I think, is : how can it remain a rvalue if the return type of the member function is `std::istream&`? I think, it is by design, a member function can transform a rvalue into lvalue.

Comment: So there should be a mixin template `can_use_as_temporary<T>`, from which you derive, and which exposes `T & lvalue() { return *this; }`!

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think that is a good feature. I'm going to start a topic on this, with few more questions I've in my mind. Lets see others opinion.

Comment: @Nawaz: I look forward to that!

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain the usage 'std::istream_iterator<int> begin(ss), end;' a bit more? What happens when the copy constructor of istream_iterator<int> is invoked? Why end is not initialized? How does that work? Thanks!