# error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Wrong form:

```
int &z = 12;
```

Correct form:

```
int y;
int &r = y;
```

***Question***:
Why is the first code wrong? What is the "**meaning**" of the error in the title?

Comment: Temporaries cannot be bound to non-constant references. int(12) is a temporary in this case.

Comment: Note that there isn't a strict *technical* reason for this restriction. It would have been just as easy to implement to *allow* mutable references to temporaries. Forbidding it is a *design decision* of C++, since such a construction would be poor design with far greater risk of being inadvertently abused than genuine utility. (I only [once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8116843/596781) found a contrived need for such a thing.)

Comment: @KerrekSB the most common need for a binding ref to rvalue object probably is `(ostringstream() << "x=" << x).str()`

Comment: @curiousguy: Yes, that's the content of the link I posted.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

C++03 3.10/1 says: "Every expression is either an lvalue or an rvalue."  It's important to remember that lvalueness versus rvalueness is a property of expressions, not of objects.

Lvalues name objects that persist beyond a single expression.  For example, `obj` , `*ptr` , `ptr[index]` , and `++x` are all lvalues.

Rvalues are temporaries that evaporate at the end of the full-expression in which they live ("at the semicolon").  For example, `1729` , `x + y` , `std::string("meow")` , and `x++` are all rvalues.

The address-of operator requires that its "operand shall be an lvalue". if we could take the address of one expression, the expression is an lvalue, otherwise it's an rvalue.

```
 &obj; //  valid
 &12;  //invalid
```

Comment: "_if we could take the address of one expression, the expression is an lvalue, otherwise it's an rvalue._" if only C++ was that simple! (but the nuance is not really relevant here) "Rvalues are temporaries" temporary what? objects?

Comment: @curiousguyRvalues are temporaries that disappear at the end of the full-expression in which they live. To simply answer why the express `int & = 12;` is invalid, the standard says a string literal is an lvalue, other literals are rvalues.

Comment: @curiousguy: Yes. Rvalues are temporary *objects*, but not all rvalues are temporary object; some are not even objects.

Comment: "_For example, 1729 , x + y , std::string("meow") , and x++ are all rvalues._" but `std::string("meow")` constructs an object of type `std::string` and yields a rvalue that designates this object, `1729` has no side-effect and yields value 1729 as an rvalue of type `int`.

Comment: "_Lvalues name objects that persist beyond a single expression._" incorrect, take: `(const int&)1;`

Comment: @AnishaKaul "_That's VERY helpful. :)_" but not technically correct

Comment: @curiousguy Accutually, `(int const &)1` is an lvalue. The standard says "The result of the expression (T) cast-expression is of type T. The result is an lvalue if T is a reference
type, otherwise the result is an rvalue.". How does this work?  The compiler would might insert a int with initial value 1 and return a const reference to that int.At lest this is true for my compiler. But the expression `1` itself is an lvalue.

Comment: @BruceAdi "_The compiler would might insert a int with initial value 1 and return a const reference to that int._" and the int "persists" for how long?

Comment: @curiousguy it dependents. the inserted int might located in stack or global storage. this might be applied to my compiler.

Comment: @curiousguy: The statement `"Lvalues name objects that persist beyond a single expression."` is a 100% correct statement. On the contrary, your example `(const int &)1` is incorrect, because It is NOT a "named" object.

Comment: @BruceAdi: `But the expression 1 itself is an lvalue`. Wrong. `1` is rvalue expression, not lvalue!

Comment: @Nawaz `(const int &)1` is a lvalue, and "Lvalues name objects that persist beyond a single expression." means that `(const int &)1` names an object that persists beyond the single expression. This is simple English - even I can understand it.

Comment: @curiousguy: I don't think he meant `Lvalues name objects` (`name` as a verb). I think he meant `lvalued *named* objects` (*named* as an adjective). He just spelled it slightly incorrectly.

Comment: @Nawaz Maybe. He'll have to clarify. I am not speculating about what he might have tried to say.

Comment: @BruceAdi "_An object is a region of storage that can be examined and stored into. An lvalue is an expression that refers to such an object._" I know that. In your answer you wrote "Lvalues name objects"; did you meant "lvalued *named* objects", as Nawaz thinks?

Answer (score 57):

```
int &z = 12;
```

On the right hand side, a temporary object of type `int` is created from the integral literal `12`, but the temporary cannot be bound to non-const reference. Hence the error. It is same as:

```
int &z = int(12); //still same error
```

Why a temporary gets created? Because a reference has to  refer to an object in the memory, and for an object to exist, it has to be created first. Since the object is unnamed, it is a *temporary* object. It has no name. From this explanation, it became pretty much clear why the second case is fine.

A temporary object can be bound to const reference, which means, you can do this:

```
const int &z = 12; //ok
```

---

#### C++11 and Rvalue Reference:

For the sake of the completeness, I would like to add that C++11 has introduced rvalue-reference, which can bind to temporary object. So in C++11, you can write this:

```
int && z = 12; //C+11 only
```

Note that there is `&&` intead of `&`. Also note that `const` is not needed anymore, even though the object which `z` binds to is a *temporary* object created out of integral-literal `12`.

Since C++11 has introduced *rvalue-reference*, `int&` is now henceforth called *lvalue-reference*.

Answer (score 10):

`12` is a compile-time constant which can not be changed unlike the data referenced by `int&`. What you *can* do is

```
const int& z = 12;
```

Comment: And `z` is bound to what? a compile-time constant?

Comment: @curiousguy, yes, what is `const char *x = "hello, world!";` pointing to?

Comment: @curiousguy: No, there is a special rule in the language to allow `const int& z = 12;` that alters the meaning of the expression to introduce an unnamed variable. The code is equivalent (semantically) to `const int __tmp = 12; const int & z = __tmp;`. As of the string literal, the same goes, the literal is stored somewhere else as a variable with no name in the program, and a pointer to it is taken (the `const char[]` decays into a pointer used to initialize `x`). In both cases, no name means that it *cannot be referred to by user code*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, yes, but why "no"? :)

Comment: Why "no" what? `z` is *not* bound to a compile-time constant *because* "there is a special rule..."

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "_there is a special rule_" so there is no **logical** explanation that could be infered from axioms. "These are the rules" is **the** correct answer.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: You can say that "bound to a compile-time constant" and "there is a special rule..." are just as vague, but the first is false and the second is true, so they are in a whole different level of validity. In n3092 (I don't have the standard here, so I am pulling from an online draft), read 8.5.3p5 where you are most interested in the last case of the list

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I think you read me wrong. What I've said is that "bound to a compile-time constant" is vague enough to make it impossible to consider it false or true.

Comment: You give no justification for this C++ behaviour the OP is asking about.

Comment: @curiousguy, be consistent, you've said "You have to understand that these are C++ rules. They exist, and don't need any justification" (not to mention the first edition). How am I to interpret your complaining of not giving what is according to  yourself is not needed?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker "_be consistent_" I am, thank you. As a said: "C++ rules () don't need any justification" Now, did **you** try to justify C++ rules in your answer? (I believe so.)

Comment: No more no less than you did, just without offending and being offended.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Technically not, you cannot (ever) bind a reference to a value (or compile time constant), the standard is quite explicit as to what actually happens: *Otherwise, a temporary of type “cv1 T1” is created and initialized from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference copy-initialization (8.5). The reference is then bound to the temporary* That is, the syntax is allowed, but the semantics are not those of binding a reference to the constant, but rather binding it to the temporary that is implictly created.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, exactly the fact that you can't bind a references to a compile-time constant leaves you the room for interpretation of this wording. Because compile-time constant is not something that can be referenced at run-time, you will have to think up another step which is creating a temporary.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, ah, I think I know what you're talking about - that you would be able to, for instance, legally return reference from the function if it was bound to some static constant, but you can't with the temporary. Yes, you're right.

Comment: @curiousguy: The rules of the language are part of the design, and more often than not, there are justifications as to why the language was designed like so. In this particular case, as in C you are not allowed to take the address of an value (it does not have one), nor can you bind a reference. Now consider a function `void f( vector<int> const & )`, which is idiomatic to pass a vector that is not to be modified. The problem now is that `f( vector<int>(5) )` would be incorrect, and the user would have to provide a different overload `void f( vector<int> v ) { f(v); }` which is trivial.

Comment: ... now because that would be painful to the users of the language, the designers decided that the compiler would perform the equivalent operation for you, in the call `f( vector<int>(5) )`, the compiler creates a temporary and then binds the reference to that temporary, and similarly if there was an implicit conversion from `5` directly. This allows the compiler to generate a single signature for the function and enables a single user implementation of the function. From there on, similar behaviour is defined for the rest of the uses of constant references for consistency.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: references are *aliases* to objects, and a value is not an object. Depending on the context, references can be just *alias* the compiler removes the reference and just uses the identifier to mean whatever the original object meant (`T const & r = *ptr;`, any later use of `r` in the function can be replaced by `*ptr`, and `r` does not need to exist at runtime) or it might have to be implemented by keeping the address of the object that it aliases (consider storing a reference as a member of an object) --which is implemented as an autodereferenced pointer.

Comment: ... because in some contexts you are in the second case, and for consistency, you cannot bind a reference to a value, as the value does not have an address.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, you again, deliver sensible speech, but I again fail to see how is it opposing what I say  (if it does). But since there's no grounds for divorce anyway, I think we'd better drop the subject ;-) I mean, seriously, you're right and I'm not in hairsplitting mood anyway.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: I think we agree, I was just trying to make the point of why references cannot be bound to values, and the need for the temporary (i.e. a reference is not a pointer, but needs an object that has an address) Sorry if I gave the impression that I was contradicting you. Cheers :)

Comment: No, not contradicting, the lack of contradiction coupled with persitence is what puzzled me. Other than that your explanations, though not exactly of revealing character, were fun to read, thanks! :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thanks for explaining this in so great detail. It is always refreshing to read your comments and posts. :-)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "_there are justifications as to why the language was designed like so._" true, but C+ rules cannot be deduced from a set of axioms. They are _ad hoc_. They were chosen to allow reasonable programs, but sometimes end-up with an unreasonable outcome: why can I do `ostringstream << 0` but not `ostringstream << "0"`: you can show the rules allow and not the other, but can you **justify** the result?

Comment: "_now because that would be painful to the users of the language, the designers decided that the compiler would perform the equivalent operation for you_" so the argument "_as in C you are not allowed to take the address of an value (it does not have one), nor can you bind a reference._" does not hold. That's the contradiction I was trying to point out.

Comment: Please take this to a chatroom instead.

Answer (score 5):

## Non-const and const reference binding follow different rules

These are the rules of the C++ language:

- an expression consisting of a literal number (`12`) is a "rvalue"
- it is not permitted to create a non-const reference with a rvalue: `int &ri = 12;` is ill-formed
- it is permitted to create a const reference with a rvalue: in this case, an unnamed object is created by the compiler; this object will persist as long as the reference itself exist.

You have to understand that these are C++ rules. They just are.

It is easy to invent a different language, say C++', with slightly different rules. In C++', it would be permitted to create a non-const reference with a rvalue. There is nothing inconsistent or impossible here.

But it would allow some risky code where the programmer might not get what he intended, and C++ designers rightly decided to avoid that risk.

Answer (score 1):

References are "hidden pointers" (non-null) to things which can change (lvalues). You cannot define them to a constant. It should be a "variable" thing.

EDIT::

I am thinking of

```
int &x = y;
```

as almost equivalent of

```
int* __px = &y;
#define x (*__px)
```

where `__px` is a fresh name, and the `#define x` works only inside the block containing the declaration of `x` reference.

Comment: Why you can, if the reference is `const` :)

Comment: But the poster's example was not `const`

Comment: Yes, I meant your wording "references are pointers to things which can change" - it's about non-cost references.

Comment: "_References are "hidden pointers"_" wrong "_to things which can change_" wrong "_things which can change (lvalues)._" wrong

Comment: @Loki: could you explain more?

Comment: "_as almost equivalent of_" references may be the moral equivalent of what you write, but that still does not answer the original question.

Comment: lvalues are **not** "things which can change"

Comment: "_You cannot define them to a constant. It should be a "variable" thing._" what about `const int&`