# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int'

Tags: c++, reference, temporary, lvalue, rvalue

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int &x)
{
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    cout << fun(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain the reason of the error ?

Thanks

Comment: you are passing constant `10`,

Comment: code_hacker: reference variable are introduced so that a variable change in a function can be reflected in Calling function but constant can't be modified that is why constant object can't referenced (and it is compilation time error).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`10` is a constant, so you can't pass a reference to it, simply because the whole concept of changing a constant is bizarre.

References were introduced to solve one of the thorny problems in C (and earlier C++), the fact that everything is passed by value and, if you want to have a change reflected back to the caller, you have to pass in a pointer and dereference that pointer within the function to get at the actual variable (for reading and writing to it).

This is something that would be *seriously* good to have in the next ISO C standard. While having to use pointers may give some of us a lot of rep on Stack Overflow, it's not doing the C programmers of the world much good :-)

The solution to your problem is simple. If you *don't* need to change the item in the function, just pass it normally:

```
int fun (int x) { ... }
```

If you *do* need to change it, well, then you'll have to pass something that *can* be changed:

```
int xyzzy = 10;
cout << fun (xyzzy);
```

Answer (score 5):

We can shorten this program down to the following:

```
int& x = 10;
```

The reason this code doesn't work is because 10 is an rvalue, and rvalues cannot bind to lvalue-references. If that was true, we'd be able to change the value of a literal (which is possible in other languages but not in C++).

Answer (score 2):

10 here is a const number and you are trying to create a non const reference to it. Either store 10 in some variable like

`int x = 10`

then pass it to function or make reference as const.

```
const int &x
```

Have it been C++11 then you can also use concept of rvalue reference, so it wont give error.

For more details see [error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293426/error-invalid-initialization-of-non-const-reference-of-type-int-from-an-rval)

Answer (score 1):

A reference (`&`) must point (reference) to a variable. A constant cannot be referenced.