# I encountered a problem in the Flattening a linked list question. When I pass the arguments by reference in the merge function I get an error why?

Tags: c++

```
/*
 * Definition for linked list.
 * class Node {
 *  public:
 *      int data;
 *      Node *next;
 *      Node *child;
 *      Node() : data(0), next(nullptr), child(nullptr){};
 *      Node(int x) : data(x), next(nullptr), child(nullptr) {}
 *      Node(int x, Node *next, Node *child) : data(x), next(next), child(child) {}
 * };
 */

Node* merge(Node* &a, Node* &b){
    
    Node* temp = new Node(0);
    Node* ans = temp;
    
    while(a!=NULL && b!=NULL){
        
        if(a->data < b->data){
            ans->child = a;
            ans = a;
            ans->next = NULL;
            a = a->child;       
        }
        else{
            ans->child = b;
            ans = b;
            ans->next = NULL;
            b = b->child;
        }
    }

    while(a!=NULL){
        ans->child = a;
        ans = a;
        ans->next = NULL;
        a = a->child;
    }
    
    while(b!=NULL){
        ans->child = b;
        ans = b;
        ans->next = NULL;
        b = b->child;
    }
    
    temp = temp->child;
    ans->child = NULL;
    return temp;
}

Node* flattenLinkedList(Node* head) 
{
    // Write your code here
    if (head == NULL || head->next==NULL) {
        return head;
    }

    return merge(head, flattenLinkedList(head->next));
}
```

```
Compilation Failed
In file included from runner.c++:21:0:
solution.h: In function 'Node* flattenLinkedList(Node*)':
solution.h:61:38: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Node*&' from an rvalue of type 'Node*'
  return merge(head, flattenLinkedList(head->next));
                                      ^
solution.h:14:7: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'Node* merge(Node*&, Node*&)'
 Node* merge(Node* &a, Node* &b){
       ^
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294009/2550406) answers your question. I found it by searching for your error `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type rvalue`

Comment: I did not understand.

Comment: @JahnviAgarwal Do not tag `dsa`.  Did you read what the `dsa` tag means?

Comment: if `merge` wants to modify its second parameter (ie its a non-const reference), then it does not make sense to pass it a temporary (the pointer returned from the `flattenLinkedList` function).

Comment: why does `merge` take two non-const references? Does merging two lists modify the heads of the two original lists?

Comment: Yes after merging head is modified

Comment: @JahnviAgarwal I've tried to explain (below in an answer) what I've read in the Q&A I've linked but tbh I am not sure at all about my interpretation. It's just my best guess. I hope somebody else can clarify it better. I have retracted my close vote because while the questions might have the same answer, your question actually also needs additional explanation for the specific case you are presenting here

Comment: Your `merge` function leaks memory. Try implementing it without calling `new`.

Comment: Why do you need `merge` parameters to be references? After merging, both become null pointers. The caller doesn't get any new information from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said the linked Q&A was not enough, here's my attempt. I hope it's not wrong, but it sounds plausible to me:

Your function signatures

```cpp
Node* flattenLinkedList(Node* head) 
Node* merge(Node* &a, Node* &b)
```

describe that `flattenLinkedList` returns a `Node*` - a pointer to a `Node`. And that `merge` takes a `Node*` *by reference*. The thing about taking a reference and using it is: the referenced object should still exist by the time you use it. In your case the referenced object is a pointer.

But because c++ is weird (in other words, I do not know enough to explain this) the scope of the argument is quite short-lived. Let's say you'd split it up, like they do [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8293426/2550406):

```cpp
{
Node* temp = flattenLinkedList(head->next);
return merge(head, temp);
}
```

This conceptually does the same thing, except that `temp` has a clear scope: once you exit the function's `{}` block by returning, `temp` will no longer exist.

If you do it both in the same line though, as you have done

```cpp
return merge(head, /* temp */ flattenLinkedList(head->next));
```

then the `temp` you return from `flattenLinkedList` might cease to exist immediately... This is the problem the compiler is pointing out (I think).

The linked question has a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293426/error-invalid-initialization-of-non-const-reference-of-type-int-from-an-rval/8294009#comment10219208_8293426) on this:

> Note that there isn't a strict technical reason for this restriction. It would have been just as easy to implement to allow mutable references to temporaries. Forbidding it is a design decision of C++

Sidenote: what is the point of having a non-const reference as an argument if you discard `temp` anyway after it is modified? You could also make the second argument of `merge` a `Node* b` instead of a `Node* &b`, right?