# Reading a list of integer in a single input line in C++

Tags: c++, integer

I'm trying to read multiple integers from a single input line into an array
eg. Input: 100 200 300 400, so the array is: a[0] = 100, a[1] = 200, a[2] = 300, a[3] = 400
The thing is, the number of integers are unknown, so the size of the array is unknown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a container that automatically resizes itself, such as `std::vector`.

For example, something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

std::string line;
getline(instream, line);
std::istringstream this_line(line);
std::istream_iterator<int> begin(this_line), end;
std::vector<int> values(begin, end);
```

Comment: I guess you meant to use `std::istream_iterator<int>` and you wanted to use appropriate parenthesis to avoid the most vexing parse.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Thanks you pointing out the wrong name.  Is that a valid way to avoid most vexing parse?

Comment: Yes, it definitely avoids the most vexing parse but unnecessarily requires the use of C++2011. A somewhat more subtle version is `std::vector<int> values(std::istream_iterator<int>(this_line), (std::istream_iterator<int>()))` (note the extra set of parenthesis around the second argument). Also, I had intentionally used `std::istream_iterator<int>` instead of `istream_iterator<int>` ;)

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Oh fine, no C++11 fun used.  C++11 would also allow using `{}` instead of `()`, to avoid parsing as a function declaration, right?

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, I think this is correct although I'm not entirely sure: the "uniform initialization syntax" is **far** from uniform and `std::vector<T>` supports initializer lists: I haven't quite wrapped my head around the interaction between those and the uniform initializations. Since `std::vector<T>` uses `std::initializer_list<T>` this should be OK (need to try it out though).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: A difference between `values{ begin, end }` and `values{{ first, second }}` perhaps?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I get this warning: `warning C4930: 'std::vector<_Ty> values(std::istream_iterator<_Ty> (__cdecl *)(std::istringstream),std::istream_iterator<_Ty> (__cdecl *)(void))': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)` and it also doesn't work properly.

Comment: When I replace `std::vector<int> values(` with `std::vector<int> values = std::vector<int>(`, everything works fine.

Comment: @LihO: Thanks, I thought most vexing parse was avoided, guess it still found a way to make it look like a function.  Re-fixed.

Comment: May I make a suggestion that avoids the most vexing parse, and is, IMO, much more readable? http://ideone.com/dUAcD

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yeah, yeah, go ahead and change it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: it seems, the constructor taking an initializer list is only taken if the values are convertible to `T`: `std::vector<int>{ 1u, 2u, 3u }` uses `std::initializer_list<int>` while `std::vector<int>{ std::istream_iterator<int>(in), std::istream_iterator<int>() }` uses the constructor taking a pair of iterators. I still need to do some reading in the standard to sort this out for me...

Comment: @DietmarKühl: most vexing parse could also be avoided by `std::vector<int>( std::istream_iterator<int>{in}, std::istream_iterator<int>{} )` couldn't it?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `std::vector` for this:

```
std::vector<int> myVector;

std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream os(line);

int i;
while(os >> i)
    myVector.push_back(i);
```

This code requires following includes: `<iostream>`, `<string>`, `<sstream>` and `<vector>`.

Comment: Please stop `abusing namepsace std;`. It's a really, really filthy habit, and it ruins the minds of all those newcomers...

Comment: I don't think it's quite as bad as Kerrek makes it out to be, but example code should be even more pristine than production code.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I know that it is not a good practice and I abuse it really quite a lot especially when I know that I'm going to write more than 5 `std::` prefixes. He made a good thing when he wrote this comment.

Comment: @LihO: As long as it`s within a limited scope, `using namespace std;` is fine.  The main complaint is related to "action at a distance", which is why it's especially bad to find it in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

Inserters and stream iterators can do this nicely:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> numbers;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(numbers));
```

Or, as @Ben Voigt has it, construct the vector from the input in one go (if that's an option):

```
std::vector numbers(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                    std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

You can replace `std::cin` by a suitable string stream if your input requirements are more complex.

Comment: Boo to `std::copy`, `std::vector` knows how to construct itself from a range.

Comment: This neglects the "single line" requirement.

Comment: What pun? Your code reads the entire standard input stream. The OP only wants a single line.

Comment: +1 for side-stepping the issue of the most vexing parse by using `std::cin`. Unfortunately, this won't work as easily if the stream is a local variable, though: in this case an extra set of parenthesis is needed.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Yeah, we discussed this a while back, where we did everything inside one single `for` loop, using an ad-hoc helper `std::stay` (the opposite of `std::move`).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Ah, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8116843/596781). Turns out that `std::stay` makes for good Googlability.

Comment: @KerreK: Whole question looks like a dupe at this point, doesn't it?

Comment: @BenVoigt: More like a tripe. :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: You don't even need `std::stay()` (not to mention that you aren't allowed to add this to `namespace std` anyway): `std::vector<int> values(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::istringstream(line) >> std::skipws), (std::istream_iterator<int>()));`.