# swap temporary tuples of references

Tags: c++, tuples, swap, rvalue

I'm writing a custom iterator that, when dereferenced returns a tuple of references.  Since the tuple itself is ephemeral, I don't think I can return a reference from operator*().  I think my iterator makes sense semantically, since it has reference semantics, even though operator* returns a value.

The issue is, when I try to call std::swap (or rather, when std::sort does), like below, I get errors because the swap expects l-values.  Is there an easy fix to this problem?

```
#include <vector>

class test {
  public:
  test()
    :v1(10), v2(10)
  {}

  class iterator {
    public:
    iterator(std::vector<int>& _v1,
             std::vector<int>& _v2)
      :v1(_v1), v2(_v2){}

    std::tuple<int&, int&> operator*(){
      return std::tuple<int&, int&>{v1[5], v2[5]};
    }
    std::vector<int>& v1;
    std::vector<int>& v2;
  };

  std::vector<int> v1, v2;
};



int main(){
  test t;
  //error, Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:3003:1: note: candidate function [with _Tp = std::__1::tuple<int &, int &>] not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument

  //deep within the bowels of std::sort ...
  std::swap(*(test::iterator(t.v1, t.v2)),
            *(test::iterator(t.v1, t.v2)));
}
```

Comment: You'll need a custom tuple-like type that supports the semantics you want.

Comment: At least in g++ `sort` calls `iter_swap` which calls `__iter_swap` which calls an unqualified `swap` which means you can create your own `swap` function that ADL will pick up. I don't have a standard reference that this is guaranteed though.

Comment: To do ADL, I'd need to write my own type that holds a tuple and write a swap for that(probably with implicit conversion to std::tuple), right?  That seems like the best solution I've heard so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [rare occasions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116843/596781) it may be desirable to get an lvalue reference to temporary. This easily achieved with a cast opposite to `std::move`:

```
template <typename T>
T & stay(T && t) { return t; }
```

Usage:

```
std::swap(stay(foo()), stay(bar()));
```

---

As you already said, if you can't change the call site, your best option may be to write your own reference wrapper and use ADL for that:

```
namespace detail
{
    struct IntRefPair
    {
        int & a, & b;
        IntRefPair(int & x, int & y) : a(x), b(y) {}
    };

    void swap(IntRefPair && lhs, IntRefPair && rhs)
    { 
        std::swap(lhs.a, rhs.a);
        std::swap(lhs.b, rhs.b);
    }
}

// ...

IntRefPair operator*() { return IntRefPair(v1[5], v2[5]); } }
```

Comment: I can't change the call to std::swap, since it's within the depths of std::sort.  How can your solution still be applied?

Comment: Buried in there: "The issue is, when I try to call std::swap (or rather, when std::sort does)".  I'll edit to make it more clear in the code snippet.

Comment: @BenJones: Yes, I see. That's a problem. Perhaps you can write your own reference wrapper, rather than rely on `std::tuple`, and use ADL? (As you already discovered.)

Comment: Using my own wrapper looks like it will break existing code that expected the dereferenced iterator to be a std::tuple, since even with an implicit conversion operator to tuple, calls to std::get fail template argument deduction.  Specializing std::get for myself isn't allowed is it :)?

Comment: @BenJones: I'm not sure, it might be? We should check. That might be a solution.

Comment: From what I could tell, it's not customizable.  I wrote my own get function and used ADL.

Answer (score 3):

The answer I came up with was to write a tuple wrapper class:

```
template<typename ... Types>
struct tupleWrapper{
   std::tuple<Types...> data;
   tupleWrapper(std::tuple<Types...> _data) : data{_data}
   {}
   operator std::tuple<Types...> () {return data;}
   std::tuple<Types...>& asTuple() {return data;}
 };

template<typename ... Types>
void swap(tupleWrapper<Types ...> t1, tupleWrapper<Types ...> t2){
  std::swap(t1.data, t2.data);
}
```

And a get function that can be found with ADL, since the conversion operator doesn't get called when doing TAD for std::get.

```
template<int N, typename ...Ts>
  auto get(tupleWrapper<Ts...> tw)->decltype(std::get<N>(tw.data)){
    return std::get<N>(tw.data);
}
```

It's not ideal, but I think it will work well enough.

Comment: I know this post is ages old, but I'm using this snippet now. Why do you pass `tw` by value in your `get` implementation?

Comment: I can't remember if it was intentional or not... sorry!  I think development of rangesv3 has made more code use stuff like iter_swap that avoids needing to do stuff like this, so you might be able to avoid this hack altogether!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's an interesting approach, I'll look into it.

Comment: For reference, I'm making a more generic version of OP's `iterator` (can iterate over any amount of any type of container)

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `std::tuple` as a data member and return a reference to that:

```
class iterator
{
public:
    iterator(std::vector<int>& _v1,
             std::vector<int>& _v2)
      : tup(_v1[5], _v2[5]) {}

    tuple_of_references& operator*() const
    {
        return tup;
    }
private:
    typedef std::tuple<int&, int&> tuple_of_references; // just to cut down size
    tuple_of_references tup;
};
```

Comment: In my actual use case, the tuple isn't constant, so it seems like this might have issues if I do something like:
auto t1 = *it;
++it;
auto t2 = *it; //now the tuples are aliased

Comment: @BenJones Are you saying it's the `const`-ness of `operator*` that's the problem? If it is, then just take away the `const`.

Comment: No, I think the example above isn't quite what I meant.  auto& t1 = *it; ++it; //operator ++ would probably change the tuple held in iterator, so t1's value changed.  auto& t2 = *it; //t1 and t2 point alias the same tuple, which doesn't make much sense

Comment: I am not sure this approach will work unless the tuple container lives a long life... So, it should be still alive after the sort procedure for sure..