# swap overload that can take l-value and r-value references and different types

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write an overload of `swap` that I expect the compiler to find through ADL. This version of `swap` can swap two arguments of different types, with the types being defined in the same namespace. This is what I thought might work:

```
#include <utility>

namespace mynamespace
{
    struct FirstStruct
    {
    };

    struct SecondStruct
    {
    };

    template<typename first_t, typename second_t>
    void swap(first_t&&, second_t&&)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I use a universal reference because I want it to work with both r-value refs (temporaries) as well as l-value refs.

However, this, and many other variants I've tried in an attempt to avoid having to write a multitude of specialized overloads, doesn't seem to work, especially when a `using std::swap` is specified before making an unqualified call to `swap`, which is what I expect most users would do.

Do I have no other option but to write `4 x 4 = 16` variants of `swap`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the purpose of swapping rvalue references.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specializing std::swap for rvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079128/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need 3 overloads:

```
template<typename first_t, typename second_t>
void swap(first_t&&, second_t&&)
{
    //...
}

 // for better match than std::swap
 void swap(FirstStruct& lhs, FirstStruct& rhs) { swap<FirstStruct&, FirstStruct&>(lhs, rhs); }
 void swap(SecondStruct& lhs, SecondStruct& rhs) { swap<SecondStruct&, SecondStruct&>(lhs, rhs); }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/801e8b42b10e6e16)