# How to use stringstream constructor in getline?

Tags: c++, stream, getline, default-constructor

Following up https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120224/390066.

Why can't I use

```
getline(stringstream(line),cell,','){}
```

instead of

```
stringstream lineStream(line); 
getline(lineStream,cell,','){}
```

?

**update**

I should have clarified that I want to use getline within a loop.

Furthermore,  I should have also noted that my initial intention was to read a file line-by-line using getline and use the line from that in the new getline that would divide on ',', which is more intuitive imo.

From what I understood so far, getline is not designed for that because it takes a non-const input and gives const token; therefore,  getline cannot be blindly recursed.

Comment: getline would change some temp object which would be always the same unchanged one.

Comment: Would it be of any significance to store value in a temporary variable...

Comment: Define `template <typename T> T & stay(T && x) { return x; }` and try: `std::getline(stay(std::istringstream(line)), cell, ',')`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Neat, except for the name:-), which suggests that it somehow extends the lifetime of the temporary.  (The use of `flush()` is the consecrated idiom, although I wouldn't say that it's particularly transparent either.  But it does work with pre-C++11.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: `stay` is the opposite of `move`. Neither actually changes the location of things :-) Maybe they should be renamed to `std::value_category_cast`!

Comment: @KerrekSB I hadn't thought of it like that.  Seen that way, it's a good name.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I'm just parroting this from [an earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8116843/596781) (second code block).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As show by @James Kanze you can.

The question is do you really want to?
The stream is destroyed at the end of the expression so you are only reading one cell from it.

If we look at this in the [context of the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c/1120224#1120224):
i.e. You can not use that in a loop:

```
std::string       line = /* Init */;
std::stringstream lineStream(line); 

std::string cell;
while(std::getline(lineStream, cell, ','))
{
    // Do stuff with cell.
}
```

If you place your code into this context it will not work as expected:

```
std::string cell;
while(std::getline(std::istringstream(line).flush(), cell, ','))
{
    // Do stuff with cell.
}
```

As the expression inside the `while()` will be fully evaluated each time. So you go into an infinte loop reading the first cell continuously.

Comment: He might want to.  If he's using `getline`, there are more efficient and more natural ways of doing this using `std::find` or `std::find_if`; it might be useful for picking off an initial numerical value, however.  (On the whole, like you, I'm skeptical.  Normally, you'd want to check the status after extraction.  But I'm sure there are cases.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: There are more efficient ways. But this is very natural to me. Using `std::find()` is more C like and requires more auxiliary code to get to the same point. So this technique is easy to teach with as all the details are handled for you while you can concentrate on the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it's ugly:

```
std::getline( std::istringstream( line ).flush(), cell, ',' );
```

The problem is that `std::getline` takes a non-const reference (which is
logical, since it is going to modify the stream), and you cannot
initialize a non-const reference with a temporary.  You can, however,
call member functions on it.  `std::istream::flush` is a member
function, which returns a non-const reference to the stream on which it
was called (and if that stream is an `std::istringstream`, doesn't do
anything else).

FWIW: you'd probably find:

```
cell = std::string( line.cbegin(), std::find( line.cbegin(), line.cend(), ',' ) );
```

a bit more efficient.  And, at least in my opinion, easier to read and
maintain.