# Reading of integers from file

Tags: c++, integer, fstream, ifstream

I have to read integers from file, that are written for example so:
The first number shows the number of the lines.

```
4
2 44
11 3
44 3
2 11
```

This should be the result:
 [2:44][11:3][44:3][2:11]

This is my code:

```
int read() {
    std::ifstream file("file.dat");
    int s;
    int p;

    if (!file) {
        std::cout<<"File cant´t be open"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }else {
    while(file>>s && file>>p) {

        std::cout<<"["<<s<<":"<<p<<"]";
    }
    /*  for(int i=0; i<count; i++) { 
            std::cout<<"["s[i]<<":"<<p[i]<<"]";
*/

file.close(); 
}
return 0;

}
```

But the result is:
[4:2][44:11][3:44][3:2]

How can I define,that the first number shows the lines,where the two numbers stay?

Comment: Why don't you just read the single integer before you start your loop? Or is the number of non whitespace lines you need to skip not known before?

Comment: You forget the first single integer

Comment: I tried so: else {
  int beginning;
  file>>beginning;
 while(file>>s && file>>p) {
  for(int i=0; i<beginning; i++) {
  std::cout<<"["<<s<<":"<<p<<"]"<<std::endl;
 }
 }        but so my numbers are shown in this example four times per couple.

Comment: @DianaPapukchieva Of course they are, you told the compiler that you want that with your `for`-loop. Get rid of that and it will print only once.

Comment: Oh,yes,i get it                                                                                              }else {
  int beginning;
  file>>beginning; 
 
  while(i<beginning ) {
  file>>s;
  file>>p;
  std::cout<<"["<<s<<":"<<p<<"]"<<std::endl;
  i++;
  
 }   So it´s correct,thanks!

Comment: You should search StackOverflow for "c++ read from file structure".  It's all about parsing the separators.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116808/read-integers-from-a-text-file-with-c-ifstream