# Can I read a file in 2d array without knowing the number of columns of a text file?

Tags: c++

I want to read a file in 2d array.
Basically File is like this

abcedf
ghijkl
mnoqre

Now i know the rows of files but i don't know the columns but col numbers are same for all rows.
Now if i do this.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++){

 fin>>value;
 row[i]=growfunction 
 }
```

With this program will keep adding all file lines to first row because there is no condition so i can make it move to second row. 
What can i do?

Thank You for your time.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::vector<std;;string>>` and the `push_back()` function as necessary.

Comment: This post would be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116808/read-integers-from-a-text-file-with-c-ifstream .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to directly read a whole line into a string and then use std::strstream to input the elements of that line into individual values in arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  std::string line;
  while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    int rowSize = line.size();
    char * row = new char[rowSize];
    std::strringstream strm;
    strm << line;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i) {
      strm >> row[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it good to teach people use C-style strings and the deprecated (i.e. should not be used) `std::strstream`?

Comment: Agreed, please make following changes `#include<strstream>` to `#include <sstream>` and std::strstream to std:stringstream.